# How to change code to prevent SQL injection in typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am writing code using nestjs and typeorm.

However, the way I write is vulnerable to `SQL injection`, so I am changing the code.

```js
//Before
.where(`userId = ${userId}`)
//After
.where(`userId = :userId` , {userId:userId})
```

I am writing a question because I was changing the code and couldn't find a way to change it for a few cases.

```js
//CASE1
const query1 = `select id, 'normal' as type from user where id = ${userId}`;
const query2 = `select id, 'doctor' as type from doctor where id = ${userId}`;

const finalQuery = await getConnection().query(`select id, type from (${query1} union ${query2}) as f limit ${limit} offset ${offset};`);

//CASE2
...
.addSelect(`CASE WHEN userRole = '${userRole}' THEN ...`, 'userType')
...

//CASE3 -> to find search results in order of accuracy
...
.orderBy(`((LENGTH(user.name) - LENGTH((REPLACE(user.name, '${keyword.replace( / /g, '', )}', '')))) / LENGTH('${keyword.replace(/ /g, '')}'))`,
'ASC')
...

//CASE4
let query = 'xxxx';
let whereQuery = '';
for(const i=0;i<5;i++)
  whereQuery += ' or ' + `user.name like '%${keyword}%'`

query.where(whereQuery)
```

I cannot use `parameter` in the `select` function.

In the above case, I am wondering how to change it.
Is it ok to not have to modify the select code?